# In Azure AD B2C, is it possible to have a password less sign in policy where user enters email and OTP is sent to associated mobile number?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

1. In Azure AD B2C, is it possible to have a password less sign in policy where user enters email and OTP is sent to associated mobile number?
2. Can we associate multiple phone numbers to a consumer account
   without custom/extension attribute?

Regarding point 1, even if we manage to create it, should we use this policy. Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you'd have to create it via custom policy.
2. Yes, via custom policy you'd have to create an additional endpoint. This endpoints points to a db with a list of phone numbers and returns true if it's in that list. As for best practice, it's dependent on the user requirements.

It's a bit tricky to develop custom policies.

Here's a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/solution-articles

Comment: Do you have any implementation Github links?

Comment: It's in Module 5 of the Course for Developers pdf: https://aka.ms/learnAADB2C
If you're not familiar with it yet, my advise is to start from Module 1

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/Readme.md

The above link has a solution for Azure AD B2C.

Password-less sign-in with email verification:

> The TrustFrameworkExtensions_passwordless_only.xml sample policy
> includes the following user journey:
>
> - Social account
> - Sign-in with email verification (passwordless)
> - Sign-up with email verification (passwordless)